# How I convert it to SQL Server please

Tags: sql-server

How can I create a SQL Server equivalent of this query?

```
SELECT m.ItemId
    ,item.NAME
    ,m.Expiratory
    ,m.t AS TotalNumber
FROM item
    ,(
        SELECT ItemId
            ,Expiratory
            ,sum(TotalNumber) t
        FROM inbox
        GROUP BY Expiratory
            ,ItemId
        ) m
WHERE (
        (
            m.ItemId
            ,m.Expiratory
            ) NOT IN (
            SELECT ItemId
                ,Expiratory
            FROM outbox
            GROUP BY Expiratory
                ,ItemId
            )
        )
    AND (item.ItemID = m.ItemId)
```

Comment: Convert what to SQL Server?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT 
    inbox.ItemId,
    item.NAME,
    inbox.Expiratory,
    t = SUM(inbox.TotalNumber)
FROM dbo.Item 
INNER JOIN dbo.inbox
ON Item.ItemId = inbox.ItemId
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Outbox
    WHERE Item = inbox.Item
    AND Expiratory = inbox.Expiratory
)
GROUP BY inbox.ItemId, item.NAME, inbox.Expiratory;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.ItemId
    ,item.NAME
    ,m.Expiratory
    ,m.t AS TotalNumber
FROM item
    ,(
        SELECT ItemId
            ,Expiratory
            ,sum(TotalNumber) t
        FROM inbox
        GROUP BY Expiratory
            ,ItemId
        ) m
WHERE (
        (
            m.ItemId
            ,m.Expiratory
            ) NOT IN (
            SELECT ItemId
                ,Expiratory
            FROM outbox
            GROUP BY Expiratory
                ,ItemId
            )
        )
    AND (item.ItemID = m.ItemId)
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support `(val1,val2) NOT IN (col1,col2)` construct, so no, this will not work in SQL Server. What have you changed here except formatting?

Comment: no thing , gust formatting

Comment: @Shawn thank you could not figure out how to post answer in a form of code.

Comment: @hasnbatal you can always use poorsql.com to format your code in proper sql readibility

Comment: I'm not good in inglish

Comment: you mean i can convert my code with this web site @uer38851

Comment: @hasnbatal I mean what you earlier pasted here can be presented in proper readable format. But it will not create logic for you. That's what i meant. your inglish is not a problem.

Comment: @hasnbatal what for what? please post it clearly.

Comment: I don't know how to convert it to sql server in part of (xx,xx) not in (select ......)

Comment: @hasnbatal I'm sorry but it's not clear at all

Comment: in where < i have aproblem > 
WHERE (
        (
            m.ItemId
            ,m.Expiratory
            ) NOT IN (
            SELECT ItemId
                ,Expiratory
            FROM outbox
            GROUP BY Expiratory
                ,ItemId
            )
        )

Comment: @hasnbatal There is another answer you can check that is good. This one will not work in SQL-Server.

Comment: @hasnbatal use `ItemId` then.